# Anyway to block visits to specific URLs, for eg via htaccess?

Tags: apache, security, .htaccess

I need to block visits to specific URLs within my site. But I am unsure how to, and is terrible at understanding the intricacies of htaccess. ^^

I need to block visits that are accessing these type of URLs, for eg.

- http://mydomain.com/katherine-blouse-on-fire
- http://mydomain.com/antique-for-preservation
- http://mydomain.com/?type=extended&name=stackoverflow

My current htaccess code

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(png|gif|ico|swf|jpe?g|js|css)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php?sef_rewrite=1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>

<Files 403.shtml>
order allow,deny
allow from all
</Files>

deny from xx.xx.xx.xx 
deny from xx.xx.xx.xx
```

What should I enter into htaccess to block these visits? And in which order? Before my current code or after?

Answer (score 1):

Add the below after your `RewriteBase /` before `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(png|...`**.** It will return a `403 Forbidden status code` to the client.

```
RewritCond %{REQUEST_URI} (?:(?:katherine-blouse-on-fire)|(?:antique-for-preservation)) [NC,OR]
RewritCond %{QUERY_STRING} type\=extended&name\=stackoverflow [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

Definition:

- [Flag F <sup>apache docs</sup>](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_f)**.**

Answer (score 0):

You may or may not wish to use `mod_alias` if you've got it available; the syntax is slightly more readable but it will only match paths (i.e. not query-strings):

```
<IfModule mod_alias.c>
Redirect 403 /katherine-blouse-on-fire
Redirect 403 /antique-for-preservation
</IfModule>
```