# How to block access to specific URL?

Tags: .htaccess

I am getting thousands of bot visits every hour to one specific URL of my website http://www.domain.com/.gtput/

I would like to block ALL traffic (human+bot) trying to access this URL. (This URL is not accessed by human, though!)

After lot of googling, I found an answer that worked from here --> [Anyway to block visits to specific URLs, for eg via htaccess?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9262390/anyway-to-block-visits-to-specific-urls-for-eg-via-htaccess). I am using following code in htaccess file to block this URL.

```
<IfModule mod_alias.c>
Redirect 403 /.gtput/
</IfModule>
```

Is there a BETTER way to block ALL traffic from accessing that one specific URL? So that I can save server resources (bandwidth etc.).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following Rule to forbid access to "/.gtput" :

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /.gtput/? [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]
```

Comment: Thank you for the help Starkeen but unfortunately after removing the code `Redirect 403 /.gtput/` and adding your code, it didn't work. As moreover now traffic (bots) started accessing the page. (One more thing that I forgot to add in the above question was that - there is no page with that url in the site).